# CLIENT side of telegram bot, is it possible?

Tags: python, bots, telegram

For telegram messenger, is it possible to create bot that resides on PC side, i.e. on user's side of telegram ?  (all telegram bot tutorials assumes you need telegram bot "from telegram side", i.e. bot that interact with user, but I need bot on other side of conversation, on PC (from my side), need bot that interact with existing telegram channels/bots/users). Is there any python bot module for this task?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: on some other internet forum I found suggestion to use this module:

https://github.com/vysheng/tg

but it seems outdated :(

Any other similar tool?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that works perfectly:
https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon